# C# Backgroundworker behaviour in Windows8

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am working on a project in **VS 2010**, i have a backgroundworker which starts another process in background. now the problem i am facing is this solution is working properly in Windows 7, but when i run the same solution in Windows 8 it get crashes.

I have compiled it on Windows 8, the following code arise the error

```
 bgworker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

> Exception:Thrown: "The Device is not ready." (System.IO.IOException) 
>   Thread:Main Thread[3304]

how to tackle this issue, kindly guide me

Comment: it's likely the code IN the background worker. Looks like you are attempting to access a disk drive.

Comment: yes it is executing a application in background, which is present in the same folder